# Как смонтировать корневой каталог в /mnt чтобы загрузится из него

Tags: ubuntu

Как смонтировать корневой каталог в /mnt чтобы загрузится из него в ubuntu 16.04 server?

Comment: Всмысле загрузить систему? Если да, то по-моему нужно смотреть `/etc/fstab` или что-то такое... в настройках etc искать. Но это если загрузчик загрузился. Но загрузчик должен быть родным.

Comment: Если система до загрузки загрузчика - то смотрите мененжеры загрузки типа grub, lilo

Comment: если буквально — то «никак»: никак невозможно «загрузиться из каталога». требуюся стандартные уточнения: что есть, что нужно, что предпринималось, почему не привело к успеху. [edit]

Comment: Я думаю, что автор спрашивает про `chroot`.